# Need help setting up udev rules to keep external hard drive from unmounting and remounting as read-only

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, hard-drive, mount, fstab

I've been having trouble with my external hard drive unmounting from my pi 3 torrentbox and then mounting as read-only with a different /dev/sd[letter]. I saw this blog post about how a user set up udev rules to automatically mount the new sd[letter] should it unmounts ( [link](http://blog.backslasher.net/automatically-mounting-usb-drives-and-surviving-reconnects.html) to his blog entry).

> **1. Identify filesystem UUID and destination directory**
>
> Use some trick (`gnome-disks` on another system, listing `/dev/disks/by-uuid` as seen earlier) to find your filesystem's UUID.
>   Let's say it's `aaDREAMa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aFILESYSaaaa`
>   Also prepare a directory to mount to. It should be empty.
>   Let's say it's `/media/dest`
>
> **2. Create fstab entry - do not use automount**
>
> Edit `/etc/fstab` to contain all configuration related to your filesystem.
>   It's not mandatory (you can specify the destination mount in the udev rule), but I think it's better to keep that configuration in a standard location. You can use something like this:
>
> `echo -e 'UUID=aaDREAMa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aFILESYSaaaa /media/dest auto >defaults,noauto 0 0' | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab`
>
> **3. Create udev rules to mount / unmount whenever the device is connected / disconnected**
>
> This is the fun part. Create a file in `/lib/udev/rules.d`. I chose `/lib/udev/rules.d/99-automount-usb.rules` to make sure it runs last (after the by-uuid symlink has been created), and put two actions in it - one will mount the device when connected, and another dismounts it when it's disconnected:
>
> `echo 'ACTION=="add", ENV{ID_FS_UUID_ENC}=="aaDREAMa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa->aFILESYSaaaa", RUN+="/bin/mount /dev/%k"' | sudo tee '/lib/udev/rules.d/99->automount-usb.rules'`
>   `echo 'ACTION=="remove", ENV{ID_FS_UUID_ENC}=="aaDREAMa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa->aFILESYSaaaa", RUN+="/bin/umount /dev/%k"' | sudo tee -a '/lib/udev/rules.d/99->automount-usb.rules'`
>
> **4. Test**
>
> Apply the settings using
>
> `sudo udevadm control --reload-rules`
>
> Now stop any processes interacting with the device (like Deluge), disconnect and reconnect it, and note the output of:
>
> `mount | grep /media/dest;ls /media/dest`
>
> If everything works, it should either return nothing when the drive is unplugged, and something like this when it is:
>
> `/dev/sdb1 on /media/dest type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)`
>   `<Files inside the mobile drive's filesystem>`

Will this still work on rpi 3? My current entry's format in #2's fstab goes something like:

`UUID=aaDREAMa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aFILESYSaaaa   /mnt/torrents   ext4 defaults,nobarrier   0  0`

do i still include `echo -e` and  `| sudo tee -a /etc/fstab` in the line?

How should #3's code look like when typing into a created rules file?

Comment: Isn't it better to try to find out why the external hard drive is unmounting? Kind of searching for the root cause, instead of solving the secondary cause?

Comment: Agreed @MatsK - How is the drive being powered? If just by the RPi USB port, try powering the drive separately. A drive that is constantly being disconnected is likely to be damaged at some point. Re-mounting RO usually indicates you need to run ```fsck``` on it.

Comment: The Hard drive is connected to a powered usb hub then from hub to RPi 3. It switches between sda1 and sdb1. I try to keep my active DLs to a minimum (2 or 3 only). The error includes cannot read block bitmap and journal being aborted and then remounting as read-only